# The Ninjas of Marvel Puzzle Quest

Tags: marvel-puzzle-quest

The Ninjas that you often encounter during Deadpool's Daily can be extremely difficult to defeat if you're chasing a three star cover. Is there a certain tactic or team of three characters that works well against them?

Furthermore, when presented with several different kinds, who should I focus on first? I have overcome them in the past, but I often feel as if victory comes via luck more than judgement. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's split it into two questions: How to fight ninjas, how to win Big Enchilada (you talk about 3* cover)

How to fight ninjas: you have several types (I don't remember names)
- the weakest: They turn into smoke = attack tiles when they die
- the normal: normal ninja occasional shuriken, etc.
- the boss ninja: has meteor hammer

First of all, you can tell which countdown tiles belong to which enemy.
When you cycle the enemies, their tile will pop up for a sec.

So I usually leave the weakest ninjas until the end because if it's one wave fight, their attack tiles don't matter.
Also you can usually kill them with one spell (even AoE - spell that hits multiple enemies)
One thing to note is that if they are stunned when they die, they don't turn to smoke.

Normal ninjas I attack regularly, just dealing with their countdown tiles.
Boss ninjas are low priority because the meteor hammer has big countdown which you can usually prevent (stunning, matching).

Now how to win big Enchilada

My go to team with only 2* characters is thormneto - Thor, Storm, Magneto.

There are 4 waves, 1st and 3rd are henchman, 2nd and 4th are heroes.
During first wave you try to have as many colors as possible without getting injured too much (small injury is fine)

You need to prioritize blue and purple, because storm's blue is crucial during wave two and magneto's purple makes more blue matches.
Ideally if you have 22 blue by the end of first round, you are good to go.
Just be sure, you use spell to finish off the last enemy, because it will be still your turn, when the heroes arrive (and they might not even pop spells)
I usually use magneto red to finish off the enemy, because it deals about 2 dmg and provides you with extra colors the explosion destroys.

In the hero round you just stun 2 enemies with storm blue which deals massive aoe and then kill the remaning hero.
Also extra help is Thor's yellow usually creates green cascades and you are better off using Storm's green, because it clears the board and destroyed tiles count in your total (so you can pop more magneto purple, or storm blue)
Rinse and repeat for rounds 3 and 4.

Anyone please help with formatting. I can do only in few hours time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, its better to take a team where you have as many of the colors covered as possible.

Against the ninjas, Ive found that the 2-star black widow is really good, as her one ability is both a heal, and an increase on the enemy countdown tiles. Really though, whatever you have strongest is probably best.

Against multiple people, focus on the one you find to be the most irritating.
For me, my order is: Daken/Bullseye > Loki > anything that can make a tile move > lieutenant > else

Daken and Bullseye because they change tiles based on what you're matching, Loki for similar reasons, but hes not as annoying (to me). Things that move tiles before things that dont, because then you can set up moves/combos.

Comment: What about the ninjas? Which one should I focus on first?

Comment: Honestly, it shouldnt really matter, they aren't very powerful. Id go for whichever one has the most countdown tiles, assuming that you can kill it before they go off